# Conditional probability with and without replacement

Tags: probability-distributions

A sample of size $r$ is taken from a population of $n$ elements. Find the probability that none

of the $N$ prescribed elements will be included in the sample, assuming the sampling to be

a) without

b) with replacement

.
Compare the numerical value for the two methods, when

(i) n=100, r=N=3

and

(ii) n=100, r=N=10

.

Comment: Brian - it is usually considered "good manners" on the site that when you receive a helpful answer, you accept it. You can accept one answer per question asked. To accept an answer, you simply click on the $\large\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it. Plus, you get +2 reputation points each time you accept an answer. But remember, you can only accept one answer per question.

Answer (score 1):

**Without replacement:** We can choose $r$ items in $\binom{n}{r}$ equally likely ways.

There are $\binom{n-N}{r}$ to do it using only allowed numbers. Divide.

**With replacement:** The probability that on any pick we miss all the $N$ "bad" ones is $\frac{n-N}{n}$. For the probability of avoiding bad ones $r$ times in a row, take the $r$-th power.